Запуск бота через ubuntu и screen
Задача. Написать скрипт, который будет запускать бота и перезапускать в случае его остановки/ошибок
Код запускается вот такой командой
cd /Bot
python3.9 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
python3.9 main.py

Создала screen чтобы работал на сервере после окончания сессии в cmd.
Но если код остановится или сервер упадёт, то бот не запустится снова, вручную надо будет всё вводить.
Чтобы бот восстановился после падения, можно использовать bot.service например:
[Unit]
Description=BOT
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/BOT
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.9 BOT/main.py
RestartSec=50
Restart=always

Но как туда вставить переменные окружения .venv?

Нужно указать путь до python в созданном окружении venv:
{ExecStart=/path/to/your/env/bin/python /path/to/your/bot/bot.py}
окружение будет активировано при запуске все установленные в нем переменные доступны
В юните сервиса нужно указать Restart=always для перезапуска при сбоях
Выполнить команду для разрешения автозапуска
systemctl enable myservice
Применить изменения командой
systemctl deamon-reload
ЗЫ: для команд нужен root или sudo
